# First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, email-template, singleemailmessage

I have `Visualforce` email template which has `recipientType="User" relatedToType="Enrollment__c"`

**Getting Following error**

```
11:53:56.0 (361868475)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[109]|System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
11:53:56.0 (362605563)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[109]|Bytes:120
11:53:56.0 (362775512)|FATAL_ERROR|System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

I have confirmed no null value passed in Below Send Email, Also i have one findings, If i remove the 
`{!recipient.` and `relatedTo.` from the email template email is sending with empty value. I tried by hard coding the Id in email still not working.

Note: I have this email in Custom Folder with Public access `Read Only` and Permission of the folder set as `This folder is accessible by all users`

I guess it wold be some permission issue, NOt able to fing the root cause , Anyone hep me on this.

**VisualForce Email**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="New Enrollment Submitted" recipientType="User" relatedToType="emitcs1__Enrollment__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
  <!-- container -->
  <body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; background-color: #efefef;"> 
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#efefef" style="max-width:600px">
    <!--L`ogo -->
    <tr style="background-color:#efefef;">
        <td align="center">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: #efefef;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom:20px;" class="logo">
                        <a href="" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="Logo" src="{!IF(relatedTo.emitcs1__User__r.Parent.emitcs1__Use_Parent_Logo_URL__c=true,(relatedTo.emitcs1__User__r.Parent.emitcs1__Logo_URL__c),(relatedTo.emitcs1__User__r.emitcs1__Logo_URL__c))}" width="210" style="display: block; font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px;" border="0" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Logo -->






     <!--copy under image -->
         <tr style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                <td>
                     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr style="background-color: #ffffff">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <!-- SECTION COPY -->
                                    <table align="center"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width:500px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="450" align="left" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif; color: #00386e;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;" class="padding-copy">
                                            <br /><br />
Dear {!recipient.name},
<br /><br />
New Enrollment has been submitted. Click Below link to view the Enrollment Details.
<br /><br />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                           <tr>

    </tr>           


<!--button--> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td style="text-align: center;font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;font-weight:300; padding: 20px;"> <span style="background-color:#2ea5f3; border: 3px solid #2ea5f3; color: #ffffff !important;font-size: 17px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 190px;border-radius: 200px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" href="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/lightning/r/emitcs1__Enrollment__c/{!relatedTo.Id}/view" target="_blank">Click here</a> </span>

                          </td> 
                        </tr> 

<!--end button-->     




                       <tr>
                                            <td width="450" align="left" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif; color: #00386e;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;" class="padding-copy">
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<span style="font-weight:500;font-size:16px;">From Safari Kid Team</span>
<br />


                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                           <tr>

    </tr>                         

                           <tr>

    </tr> 
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<!--end copy under image -->




</table>
</body>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

```
EmailTemplate tpl = (EmailTemplate)[select Id   FROM EmailTemplate 
                                            WHERE DeveloperName = 'Enrollment_Submitted' limit 1];
    User u= [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id =:tempFamily.emitcs1__Service_Center__r.OwnerId];

if(u.Email != null){

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                       
                String[] toAddresses = new String[] {u.Email};
                    Id UserId = UserInfo.getUserId();                        
                email.setTemplateId(tpl.Id); 
                email.setReplyTo('support@safarikid.com');
                email.setSenderDisplayName('Safari Kid');        
                email.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
                email.setWhatId(enrollId); 
                email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                SendemailList.add(email); 
            }
            if(SendemailList.size() > 0){
                 List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(SendemailList); 
                if(results[0].success){
                    System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');    

                }else {
                    System.debug('The email failed to send:  ' +  results[0].errors[0].message);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, verify the following permissions on the affected user's profile:

> 1. 'Send Email' permission is enabled.

And try this  too

```
if(u.Email != null && u.Email!='')
```

If you need any more help let me know ?

Comment: Yes `Send Email` is `Checked` for that user.

Comment: Check all the email permission in that profile and marked as true

Comment: In `General User Permission` section I see `Mass Email` and `Send Email` both are checked

Comment: if(u.Email != null && u.Email!='') try this too

Comment: No, Still same issue

Comment: Can you try to comment ``` email.setWhatId(enrollId);  ``` this line and check again ? Thank you for your patience

Comment: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Read access denied for emitcs1__Enrollment__c, controller action methods may not execute.: [] Getting this error

Comment: Do you have read access - emitcs1__Enrollment__c, on this ?? please give all read and create permission on all the fields and then it will work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108630/discussion-between-sfdc-beginner-and-sahil-malhotra).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm),

> **setWhatId(whatId)**
>
> If you specify a contact for the targetObjectId
>   field, you can specify an optional whatId as well. This helps to
>   further ensure that merge fields in the template contain the correct
>   data.

In your code, you set a `User Id` to `targetObjectId` field.